# What does Matplotlib hist() do with a 2-D numpy array input?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Suppose I have a 2-D Numpy array. It's supposed to represent the learned weights of a PyTorch linear layer. Below I'm creating an example array full of Gaussian random numbers.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(size=(4, 768))
print(data.shape) # (4, 768)
```

I then try to use the Matplotlib function [hist()](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) to create a histogram of the values. I'm using Jupyter Notebook (Google Colab). When I call the function like below (by passing in the original 2-D array), it takes a *long time* to complete, and the visual output is quite bizarre.

```py
%%time
_ = plt.hist(data, bins=100)

# Result:
# CPU times: user 48.5 s, sys: 737 ms, total: 49.2 s
# Wall time: 49.2 s
```

[image]

On the other hand, when I reshape the 2-D array into a 1-D array with `reshape()`, the `hist()` function completes almost immediately, and the visualization has the shape of what I would expect, namely a Gaussian curve.

```py
data = data.reshape(-1)
print(data.shape) # (3072,)
```

```py
%%time
_ = plt.hist(data, bins=100)

# Result:
# CPU times: user 70.7 ms, sys: 2.01 ms, total: 72.7 ms
# Wall time: 70.9 ms
```

[image]

So **what exactly is going on with my first attempt where I pass in a 2-D array**? Why does it take so long? What does the visualized graph represent?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You get 768 histograms with your 4 values each distributed in 100 bins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am rather surprised that matplotlib, unlike numpy, does not flatten the input array first. However, the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) states that the input `x` can be an `(n,) array or sequence of (n,) arrays`. This is how matplotlib interprets your input - 768 arrays of shape (4,) that are displayed as in your output as 768 histograms in one graph. You don't see much because the bars are rather thin with 76800 bars to display - an increase in figure size and resolution will probably improve that. The opposite case of `data = np.random.normal(size=(768, 4))` reveals this because now only 400 bars have to be displayed:

[image]

But we can also have a look at what matplotlib returns:

```
hist_count, hist_bins, hist_bars = plt.hist(data, bins=100)
print(hist_count.shape)
>>>(768, 100)
print(hist_bars)
>>><a list of 768 BarContainer objects>
```

Or for an even simpler version:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(123)
data = np.random.normal(size=(4, 5))
print(data.shape) #(4, 5)

hist_count, hist_bins, hist_bars = plt.hist(data, bins=6)

print(hist_count.shape) #(5, 6)
print(hist_count)
#[[0. 1. 2. 0. 0. 1.]
# [1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
# [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 2.]
# [0. 1. 1. 0. 2. 0.]
# [0. 0. 3. 1. 0. 0.]]
print(hist_bins) #[-2.42667924 -1.65457769 -0.88247613 -0.11037458  0.66172697  1.43382853  2.20593008]
print(hist_bars) #<a list of 5 BarContainer objects>
plt.show()
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The documentation doesn't give much information on how `plt.hist()` treats a 2-D array. It's not intuitive to me that it would produce `768 arrays of shape (4,) that are displayed as in your output as 768 histograms in one graph`.

Comment: I don't know the inner workings of matplotlib but maybe this is (if not intended, I mean) a side effect because they use similar routines to plot `hist()` and `hist2D()`? Just a guess, if somebody with more insight posts an answer, do not hesitate to accept the better answer.